# MongoDB Compass GUI: Error importing: Callback called multiple times

Tags: windows, mongodb

I am completely new to MongoDB. Just downloaded and installed [MongoDB Community Edition](https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/community) on my local Windows pc. The MongoDB Service is running, and I was able to connect to this local cluster. I have created a collection, and am trying to use the Compass GUI to import a [JSON-File](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/e210438bc21fdea4edaf5d08c0dc109e20210408165115/ae7208ee8a47d70533027763653e275920210408165130/8f9181), which I have verified to contain valid JSON.

When I choose Add Data => Import File

> [image]

and select the file I want, I get the following error:

> Error importing: Callback called multiple times

> [image]

If, instead of chosing Import File, I chose Insert Document

> [image]

and manually paste the entire file contents into the following dialog, the document is succesfully added to the Database.

I'd like to import multiple documents/files at once, so manually copy-pasting each one isn't really an option. Why would I be getting this error?

> Error importing: Callback called multiple times

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you. Here is an example of how to solve it:

```
[
    {
    "BMW" : ["BMW1", "BMW2", "BMW3"],
    "Audi" : ["Audi1", "Audi2", "Audi3"]

    }
]
```

All you need to to is to place your object into [  ].